# C# Object scope (easymodbus)

Tags: c#, object, scope

I´m trying to initialize the connection in one method and use the connection in another but no matter what I do the object can not be found?

Ok I hear you and change my ways :)
Here is the most relevant code.

Basically I want to connect and assign the com-port with buttonConnect_Click
And then read the registers with another button or timer.

I understand why the below code does not work, but how do I make it work?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {



        public void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
                        ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient(comboBoxCOMPorts.SelectedItem.ToString());
           modbusClient.Connect();
        }

        private void readRegister()
        {   


                int[] register = modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(Convert.ToInt32(textboxRegisterattlasa.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textboxAntalregister.Text)); //startadress, quantity of addresses
                foreach (int name in register)
                {  
                    listBoxOutput.Items.Add("Register " + Convert.ToInt32(textboxRegisterattlasa.Text) + " = " + Convert.ToString(name));                    
                }
            }
```

Comment: While it's fine in some situations to show the whole class, you should still also show just the relevant code. I don't want to read your whole class when much of it has nothing to do with the code in question. Also, if you're getting an error you should give specifics about that.

Comment: Shouldn't you evaluate `modbusConneted == false` in your if? In which method you try to initialize and in which you try to use the connection?

Comment: Please edit your question to show only relevant code.

Comment: @JeeyBee I would replace all of the foreach loops where you are loading the combobox and use the `Items.AddRange()` of the `string[]` you have declared. read here - [ComboBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a second local variable named `modbusClient` in your `readRegister()` method:

```
private void readRegister()
{   
    if (modbusConnected == true)
    {
        /* Bad idea */
        ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient(comboBoxCOMPorts.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

The scope of that variable named `modbusClient` is the `if` block where it's declared. You are not assigning a value to the *field* named `modbusClient`. You are assigning a value to completely different variable which happens to have the same name. Everything you do with `modbusClient` in that `if` block is being done to the wrong instance of `ModbusClient`.

I make a habit of naming fields with an underscore prefix:

```
private ModbusClient _modbusClient = null;
```

And local variables without the prefix. That way, you always know what you're looking at.

**Solution**

If you want to assign to the field named `modbusClient`, don't declare a new variable that hides it. Just assign to `modbusClient`:

```
private void readRegister()
{
    //  Don't you want to do this if it's NOT connected?
    if (!modbusConnected)
    {
        modbusClient = new ModbusClient(comboBoxCOMPorts.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

And you don't need to compare a boolean value to `true` (or actually `false`, if I correctly understand the intent of the code). `if (!modbusConnected)` would the idiomatic way to write that.

Comment: Thanks, I did not get it at first but now I do and it workes just fine now to first create the object in the begining and then in the read register method only use
modbusClient = new ModbusClient(comboBoxCOMPorts.SelectedItem.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat I see a few problems. `modbusConnected` is only set to `true` in the `if` block that only executes if `modbusConnected` is already `true`, so your entire logical flow is wrong.

If you'd like more specific help you need to be more specific about your problem. What is happening? What do you want to happen instead?